# To byte conversion in c++

Tags: c++

i tried making a c++ function that takes in a pointer and then returns a pointer to a char array representing the bytes

```cpp
char* toBytes(void* src, int byteSize) {
        char convertedToBytes[byteSize];
        memcpy(&convertedToBytes, src, byteSize);
        return _strdup(convertedToBytes);
    }
```

though when using it and checking each char i see the output is 3 0 ffffffffd ffffffffd instead of 3 0 0, here is the full code:

```cpp
int32_t i_lengthOfCommand = 3;
char *s_lengthOfCommand = toBytes(&i_lengthOfCommand);
printf("%x %x %x %x", s_lengthOfCommand[0], s_lengthOfCommand[1], s_lengthOfCommand[2], s_lengthOfCommand[3]);
```

stdout: 3 0 ffffffffd ffffffffd

PS: i know there is no support for big/little endian

Comment: `sizeof(src)` is going to be the same no matter what you send to the function. A `void*` will likely have the size 8 or 4 on your machine.

Comment: Or not to byte conversion.

Comment: That is the question.

Comment: what do you  mean quentin?

Comment: I'm guessing Quentin means that you're not actually converting anything, you're just trying to copy. Twice. Second time as string. Why?

Comment: because im making a socket application and the method send() takes in a char* buf as a buffer to send

Comment: The function signature of `toBytes` does not match between your code blocks. Which is correct? As is, this is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a `std::string`:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::string toBytes(const T& src) {
    return {reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&src),
            reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&src) + sizeof src};
}
```

or if you don't need to be able to change the content, a `std::string_view`:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::string_view toBytes(const T& src) {
    return {reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&src),
            sizeof src};
}
```

You can then use either with `send()` etc:

```cpp
auto res = toBytes(i_lengthOfCommand);
send(sockfd, res.data(), res.size(), flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function. And without explicitly passing the size of the array to a function, the pointer's length can never be correctly inferred.

Just use a cast to get what you want:

```
int32_t i_lengthOfCommand = 3;
char *s_lengthOfCommand = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i_lengthOfCommand);
printf("%x %x %x %x", s_lengthOfCommand[0], s_lengthOfCommand[1], s_lengthOfCommand[2], s_lengthOfCommand[3]);
```

On a little endian system, such as all Intel chips, the above code will print
`3 0 0 0`.  the least significant byte value in i_lengthOfCommand will get printed first.

On a Big Endian system, it would print `0 0 0 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's look.

```
char* toBytes(void* src) {
    char convertedToBytes[sizeof(src)];
    memcpy(&convertedToBytes, src, sizeof(src));
    return _strdup(convertedToBytes);
}
```

Let's start with this. `char` is signed. So some of the values will be positive, and some will be negative. You should use `unsigned char` instead.

The last line of your method is troubling. It assumes you have a C-style string, but you don't.

C-style strings are a series of characters with one at the end that is a zero-byte. And characters are represented in ASCII. That `strdup()` call is going to return garbage, because you have random non-ASCII data in your array.

You are probably on 64-bit architecture, so your array is 8 bytes long with no guarantee of a null byte. But if the address is low enough, you have a LEADING null byte.

Let's say `src` points to address 0x00 00 00 00 12 34 56 78. I put spaces in to make a point. That's eight bytes with their hex values.

So now your `strdup` is going to see the leading 00 and say, "Oh, end of string". But of course, your address could be far more complicated than this example, and it could be 8 bytes of non-zeros, or anything in between. Not good.

`strdup()` is the wrong method. What you have to do is build a string as you go. The easiest way is to use one of the various number-to-string methods. Such as this:

```
std::string result;
char holder[10];
for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(src); ++index) {
    sprintf(holder, "%0x", convertedToBytes[index]);
    result += holder;
}
```

Then if your method returns a `std::string`, you can return result.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the main issue that `sizeof(src)` is not the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is for endian support have a look at the boost endian library:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html

Here's a example of enforcing big endian https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html#buffers_example

Generally speaking you want to establish of the library use case then making the necessary conversions not make a general library then find out it doesn't fit your use case. If it's just endian support boost endian is simpler then rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong here

```
char* toBytes(void* src, int byteSize) {
    char convertedToBytes[sizeof(src)];
    memcpy(&convertedToBytes, src, byteSize);
    return _strdup(convertedToBytes);
}
```

first

```
char convertedToBytes[sizeof(src)];
```

will always allocate 4 or 8 bytes depending on whether 32 or 64 bit executable. You cannot find the size of an array from a pointer that points at it. I mean you already pass in the length as the second arg

Next why do you have an intermediate buffer anyway

```
    memcpy(&convertedToBytes, src, byteSize);
```

But this is incorrect anyway, you need

```
    memcpy(convertedToBytes, src, byteSize);
```

Then you copy the bytes to the heap. But `strdup` needs a null terminated string, there is no guarantee that your void* points to such a thing

You function doesnt 'convert' anything all it does is a very fiddly `memcpy`

The whole thing can be replaced by

```
   char* toBytes(void* src, int byteSize) {
        return (char*)src;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider something more modern (post `C++17`). I would probably do something more like this, utilizing `std::array`.

```
template<typename T>
std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)> toBytes(T const& t)
{
    std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)> a;
    std::copy((std::byte const*)&t, (std::byte const*)(&t + 1), a.data());
    return a;
}

in main()
{
    int32_t i_lengthOfCommand = 3;
    auto s_lengthOfCommand = toBytes(i_lengthOfCommand);
    printf("%x %x %x %x", int(s_lengthOfCommand[0]), int(s_lengthOfCommand[1]), int(s_lengthOfCommand[2]), int(s_lengthOfCommand[3]));
}
```

The benefit of using a `std::array` is that you don't risk dangling pointers or memory leaks, it remembers its length and is easily iterable. For example:

```
for(auto b: s_lengthOfCommand)
    std::cout << std::hex << b << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: @user17732522  Nicely spotted, thanks.